# How much access would a Wordpress Plugin developer need?

Tags: wordpress

I'm thinking of hiring a developer to design a Wordpress plugin for my site.  How much access do you think they would require?

Comment: what do you mean by how much access?

Comment: Please explain much better. Is the plugin specific for youre site, will you install it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about giving him an access to the actual site live, I would say a developer does not need to access a wordpress site to create some general plugin

But if your pluing have something to do with your actual data on the website, he would need an account as editor to be able to test check if the plugin is working well.

An ftp account might be needed to deploy the developed plugin into your website.

> #### but it really depends on what the plugin is doing regarding your content to say if a developed needs to access your website or not.